# Kendo ui grid create aggregate function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Is there a way to create an aggregate function in kendo?

I am trying to make a sum in a grid, if I use the sum function defined by kendo it just concatenates the numbers like they are string. My actual solution is to change the js from kendo and to put there mysum function.

It works like a charm but there should be a better solution, I think.

View code:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                   pageSize: 20,
                   data: products,
                   autoSync: true,
                   schema: {
                       model: {
                         id: "ProductID",
                         fields: {
                            ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                            ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                            Category: { defaultValue: { CategoryID: 1,CategoryName:"Beverages"} },
                            UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true,min: 1} }
                         }
                       }
                   },
                   aggregate: [ { field: "ProductName", aggregate: "count" },
                                { field: "UnitPrice", aggregate: "mysum" }]
                });

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 430,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [
        { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name", footerTemplate: "Total Count: #=count#" },
        { field: "Category", title: "Category", width: "160px", editor: categoryDropDownEditor, template: "#=Category.CategoryName#" },
        { field: "UnitPrice", title:"Unit Price", width: "120px", footerTemplate: "Total Sum: #=mysum#" },
        { command: "destroy", title: " ", width: "90px" }],
    editable: true
 });
```

And kendo ui added function:

```
mysum:function(e,t,n){return (e || 0) + parseFloat(n.get(t))}
```

Comment: Please share your code for View and script.

Comment: For Kendo library I create the function:
mysum:function(e,t,n){return (e || 0) + parseFloat(n.get(t))}

Comment: And for the call in my View file:
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                       ...,
                       aggregate: [ { field: "ProductName", aggregate: "count" },
                                    { field: "UnitPrice", aggregate: "mysum" }]
                    });

Comment: { field: "UnitPrice", title:"Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px", footerTemplate: "Total Sum: #=mysum#" }

Comment: Please edit your question to share the script and view.. Sharing the code in this way-in comment is not good practice

Comment: I edited the answer, but it is not displaying properly, don't know why..

Comment: Note that UnitPrice is a float and not a integer..

Comment: I don't understand : "just concatenates the numbers like they are string"? The latest Kendo UI just seems to work fine?

Comment: If I have a column with 5 and 7, the total will be 57 instead of 12.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm late but if it can help someone.

I've faced the same problem once and I implemented a solution which can help you to use custom aggregate function in groupFooterTemplate.

Link to the project [here](http://christfriedbalizou.github.io/kendo-grid-custom-aggregate-function-hack/)

```js
function myAggregate(data){
 // Data here is a list of data by group (brilliant right! :-) )
 // Do anything here and return result string
}

var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
  ...
  columns: [
  { field: '', title: '', groupFooterTemplate: myAggregate
  ]
  ...
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- YOUR CSS HERE -->
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <div id="#grid"></div>
    ...
    <script>// jQuery here </script>
    <script>// kendo.all.min.js here </script>
    <script src="kendo.aggregate.helper.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.